# Downloading a libgdx Project Gradle Problems

Tags: java, android-studio, github, libgdx

So my friends and I are making a game for Android and we are using Android studio. We are using libgdx. We are also learning how to use github. Anyways, using Android Studio, I uploaded the basic libgdx setup. The one that just displays the Bad Logic image. My friend downloads it from github using Android studio but there are errors everywhere. It says that it can't find the badlogic package and it gives the following error:

This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.

I know that libgdx uses gradle. So what is the problem? Why can't we simply upload and then download a simple project?

Thanks!

Comment: Try re-importing your project to finish the conversion to Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `.gradle` directory and re-import the project or use the Setup App Installer from [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html) to create a new gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I finally figured it out.

Basically, when I imported the project, I was just importing with existing project files. These are the steps I took to get it fixed.

Check out from Version Control using Android Studio and the welcome screen.

When asked to open, say NO.

Go to the folder that is associated with the repo.
Create a local.properties file there and in that file it should have

```
sdk.dir = /YOUR/PATH/TO/SDK/HERE
```

Then go back to Android Studio.
Click Import Project and select the folder that has it in there.

From then on, it should work forever as the .gitignore file that is generated by libgdx will ignore the local.properties file when pushed. I hope this helps someone!